# Location returning null on some devices

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I have been working in an Application where i need to fetch the current location of users. For the same, I added the **COARSE_LOCATION** AND **FINE_LOCATION** permissions in Manifest file.

I also added the **Runtime permission** to the App and i checked that the permissions are enabled in the App Info.

I have been using the below code to fetch the user's location.

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        } else {
            Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            List<String> providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
            if (null != locations && null != providerList && providerList.size() > 0) {
                double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
                double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                        cityname = listAddresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        countryname = listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                        regionname = listAddresses.get(0).getSubLocality();

                        System.out.println("Location updates = " + cityname + regionname + countryname);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

This piece of code works good on some devices (REDMI NOTE 3, REDMI NOTE 4, MOTO E) and in some devices it returns null(SAMSUNG J7, MOTO G).

Did i went wrong anywhere? Any advise can be really great full for my project and my learning.

Comment: where does it return null please specify..

Comment: tey initializing both the locationManager and the provider in the else part..

Comment: Location locations = getLastKnownLocation(); locations is being returned as null

Comment: @SantanuSur I tried it too... same result

Comment: I had the same problem in which getLastKnownLocation() returned null.
The workaround (not deploy-able solution) was to open up Google Maps and then launch the app. The above method returns null when the device has just been factory reset and location data is not available. My solution was to use  FusedLocationProviderClient instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I put `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` code inside loop until I get current location latitude and longitude. See below code :

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

                 Location location = null;
                 do {
                     location = getLastKnownLocation();
                  }
                  while (location == null);

                   currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                  currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
  } 




private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = null;
            try {
                l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null
                    || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        if (bestLocation == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (location == null) {

            do{
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }while (location == null);

            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("locationLinster",message);
}else{
      String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("locationLinster",message);
}
```

This really help to kick start the Provider... it takes time if our having this problem for the 1st time. But when it kicks in. it works like a dream.

Thanks @RG